Godot GridMap Not Outputting with no error message
Im thinking of developing a roguelike, Mystery Dungeon-like, automatically generated maze game using the game engine Godot 3.x Godot.
The automatically generated maze uses a digging method instead of a maze with rooms like Rogue. Reference website for automatic maze generation using hole digging method Reference website 1. Reference website 2 for automatic maze generation using the digging method Reference website 2.
Source code of self-made maze automatic generation program for Godot (GDScript).
extends Spatial

var maze_width = 10

var maze_height = 10

var _maze_width = maze_width * 2 + 1

var _maze_height = maze_height * 2 +1

const grid_wall = 0

const array_out_of_range = -1 #outside the maze

const array_passage = 0 #aisle
const array_wall = 1 #wall

class Array2D:

    var _width = 0

    var _height = 0

    var _pool = []

    func _init(w:int,h:int) -> void:

        _width = w

        _height = h

        for j in range(h):

            for i in range(w):

                _pool.append(0)

    func fill(v:int) -> void:

        for j in range(_height):

            for i in range(_width):

                _pool[i + j * _width] = v

    func setv(i:int,j:int,v:int) -> void:

        if i < 0 + 1 or i >= _width - 1:

            return #outside the maze

        if j < 0 + 1 or j >= _height - 1:

            return #outside the maze

        _pool[i + j * _width] = v

    func getv(i:int,j:int) -> int:

        if i < 0 + 1 or i >= _width - 1:

            return array_out_of_range #outside the maze

        if j < 0 + 1 or j >= _height - 1:

            return array_out_of_range #outside the maze

        return _pool[i +j * _width]

    func dump() -> void:

        print("[array2D]")

        for j in range(_height):

            var s = ""

            for i in range(_width):

                s += "%d, "%getv(i,j)

            print(s)
            
            
            
var _array = Array2D.new(_maze_width,_maze_height)

onready var gridmap = $GridMap 

# Declare member variables here. Examples:

# var a = 2

# var b = "text"


# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.

func _ready() -> void:

    #pass # Replace with function body.

    _regenerate()

    _redraw()
    

func _regenerate() -> void:

    _array.fill(array_wall)
    
    var xstart = 1

    var ystart = 1

    while xstart % 2 == 1:

        xstart = randi()%_maze_width

    while ystart % 2 == 1:

        ystart = randi()%_maze_height
        
    
    _dig(xstart,ystart)
    
    _array.dump()
    
func _dig(x:int, y:int) -> void:

    _array.setv(x,y,array_passage)
    
    var dir_list = [

        Vector2(-1, 0),

        Vector2(0, -1),

        Vector2(1,0),

        Vector2(0,1)

    ]

    dir_list.shuffle()

    for dir in dir_list:

        var dx = dir.x

        var dy = dir.y
        
        if _array.getv(x + dx * 2, y + dy * 2) == array_wall:
            
         #2 space ahead is a wall so you can dig
            _array.setv(x + dx, y + dy, 0)
            
     #Dig the next hole with recursive call
            _dig(x + dx * 2, y + dy * 2)
            
#GridMapに反映する

func _redraw() -> void:

    gridmap.clear()

    for j in range(_maze_height):

        for i in range(_maze_width):

            if _array.getv(i,j) == array_wall:

                gridmap.set_cell_item(i, 1, j, 0)
    
# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.

#func _process(delta):

#   pass

Although this source code does not result in a syntax error,
the maze will not be automatically generated.
In the current source code (Godot 3.X) the maze is not actually reflected in the GridMap node.
Are there any descriptions that I am missing? Why won't any errors show? And why is the node not being generated?
I am at a loss.
